# Обратная операция вычисления объема фигуры

Tags: python, pandas, математика, numpy, python-3.6

Я хочу реализовать функцию (или использовать уже реализованную) для решения следующей задачи:

Известен объем фигуры. Длина, ширина и высота неизвестны. Известно, что ширина и высота не могут превышать 2.4 метра. Длина не ограничена.

Необходимо подобрать **любые** длину, ширину, высоту фигуры, отвечающие требованиям задачи.

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: фигура то какая ?

Comment: Проблем... Ширина = высота = 2.4 м.  Длина = Объем/(2.4)^2...

Comment: Прошу пощения, не указал сразу: прямоугольник или квадрат.

Comment: Как вы себе представляете объём прямоугольника?

Comment: @Xander, Ну я все-же полагаю что куб и параллелепипед, автор оговорился )))

Comment: Куб - корень третей степени от объема.

Comment: *Прошу пощения, не указал сразу: прямоугольник или квадрат* - после этого вопрос иначе как стёбом, заслуживающим минуса, считать не могу. В каком классе учат объем параллелепипеда?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример кода

```
def get_dimensions(volume, max_height, max_width):
    # x*y*z=volume
    # x< max_height
    # y< max_width
    return [max_width, max_height, volume/(max_height*max_width)]

def get_dimensions_equal(volume, max_height, max_width):
    # x*y*z=volume
    # x< max_height
    # y< max_width
    # x~y~z
    d = volume**(1/3)
    x=d
    y=d
    if d>=max_width:
        y=max_width
    if d>=max_height:
        x=max_height

    z=volume/(x*y)

    return [x, y, z]


print(get_dimensions(30, 2.4, 2.4))

print(get_dimensions_equal(300, 2.4, 2.4))
```